# Calling Windows API using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

How to lock the screen (most important), change the sound, lock the keyboard and etc using VB.NNET?

I know it's quite easy to do it using C++ .Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a P/Invoke. You will have to look up the specific API calls you want to implement and use them.

Here is some info on P/Invoke.

- http://www.pinvoke.net/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/PInvoke.aspx

FYI, if you are planning anything anything malicious (it sounds like you might be), please don't.

Comment: I am going to lock my students' pc. Remotely. *Evil grin* 
Thanks for the info.

Comment: http://www2.smarttech.com/st/en-US/Products/SynchronEyes+Classroom+Management+Software/default.htm